# How to set up a private Docker repository with Artifactory OSS?

Tags: docker, registry, artifactory

I tried to set up a private docker repository using Artifactory OSS (open source version) but could not find how to do it. The online documentation is about using the licensed Artifactory product as a docker repository.

Does anyone know how to set it up in Artifactory OSS?

I installed and started Artifactory OSS, but could not find docker package information. The Package View feature is disabled in OSS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Artifactory Comparison Matrix](https://jfrog.com/open-source/), Artifactory OSS only supports Maven, Gradle and Ivy.

To use the Artifactory Docker package management you have to purchase Artifactory Pro, Artifactory Cloud or Artifactory Enterprise. Another solution is to use [Nexus Repository OSS](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss) which include this feature in the open source version.